# Forecast vs Prediction: What is the difference?

Tags: prediction, forecast, reference-request, forecasting, definitions

I use the two terms as follows:

A **prediction model** gets features (which can be a time series) as input and gives a fixed-length output (might be multiple values, but "atomic" in some sense)

Examples:

- Dog vs Cat
- Spam vs No Spam
- Weather for tomorrow
- Sales of next month

A **forecasting model** gets a time series as input and outputs a single time series.

Examples:

- Amount of airline passengers: You can predict the value for the next month, but a forecast can be over an arbitrary time frame (with deteriating quality, of course)
- Weather
- Sales

I've never seen textbook definitions of those terms. Do you know any source that compares the two terms?

Bonus points if you give me a good German translation for both terms. By now, I call both "Vorhersage" - I have the impression there is no other German word for it.

Comment: Simply stated, forecasting is prediction using time series data.

Comment: @AnkitSeth This is what [Daniel Chepenko](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/33750/8820) says.

Answer (score 1):

Prediction is more general term.
It can be defined as a an expectation for a combination of different predictors (random variables).

Forecasting would be a subset of prediction and mostly related to time-series. Any time you predict into the future it is a forecast. All forecasts are predictions, but not all predictions are forecasts.

Moreover, forecasting always have error, that is why we have confidence interval of 5%, 2.5%, 1% and residuals for modeling. There is no such thing as so called "perfect forecasting", but we can maximize the model accuracy.

On contrast, prediction sometime can be perfect. I also believe that model should follow data not the other way around.

Comment: Do you have sources supporting your definitions?

Comment: https://www.analyticbridge.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/difference-between-prediction

Comment: A forum. I take that as a "no".

Comment: @MartinThoma https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65287/difference-between-forecast-and-prediction

Answer (score 0):

**Forecast is more probabilistic events and is used for more certain events**. Example of predictions could be predicting future stock prices, house prices, percentage of house owners buying home insurance etc. Each model is made up of a number of predictors (variables) and based on predictors we can create a predictive model. Predictions relies on methodologies like **Logistic Regression** (predict values based on prior observation of the data set), **Decision trees** (prediction of every possible outcome of a decision), **Time series analysis** (related to time intervals).

Prediction is utilized more in business and economics while **forecasting takes place in weather and earthquakes** and it is always associated with a **time dimension** in the future. Prediction is the subset of Forecasting. For every forecast we will do one or more prediction.

You can read more [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-prediction-and-forecasting-1).

Comment: Do you have any trustworthy sources supporting your definitions? Please see that this question has the `reference-request` tag.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/difference-between-forecast-prediction-lakshminarayanan-t-p

Comment: @NedzadG Please look at this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65287/difference-between-forecast-and-prediction

Answer (score 0):

I guess the same as between Water and Dihydroxy-oxygen. One is in the common language, the other refers to a scientific discipline.

- Forecasts are qualitative, prediction may (or may not) be qualitative.
- Forecasts are based on an explicit model, prediction may (or may not) be based on intuition or medium powers.
- Forecasts are made by fitting the parameters of the model, prediction may (or may not) use gestimate or bestimate for the parameters.
- Forecasts are corrected for seasonality and other exogenous factors, prediction may (or may not) indicte a trend.
- Forecasts errors and computed *a priori* at the time of the forecast, prediction may (or may not) reveal to be right.
- Forecast use algorithms, prediction may (or may not) use crystal balls, cards, expert (or not expert) judgment.

Not that predictions are necessarily bad. Simply that all forecasts are predictions.